# How to append rows of one dataframe to another based on column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe `df1`

```
city      population       ratio      approval
NY          10000          3:4        yes
LA          20000          1:2        no
FL          20000          1:3        yes
```

Also, my second `df2` looks like

```
city      population     ration     approval
 NY        20000          1:4       accepted
 FL        20000          5:4       declined
```

my third `df3` looks like

```
city      population    approval
NY        20000          yes
FL        10000          no
```

How can I append all these dataframes into a single dataframe based on column names? And I've tried a couple of solutions but `df3` doesn't contain all the columns compared to `df1` and `df2`, I'm a bit stuck here.

Desired result

```
city    population         ratio         approval
 NY          10000          3:4            yes
 LA          20000          1:2            no
 FL          20000          1:3            yes
 NY          20000          1:4           accepted
 FL          20000          5:4           declined
 NY          20000          none            yes
 FL          10000          none            no
```

Comment: concat? `pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])` or `pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Is this a typo: `ration`?

Comment: @PanwenWang I believe so too. `ration` in second df should be `ratio`